# How to parse big string U-SQL Regex

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

I have got a big CSVs that contain big strings. I wanna parse them in U-SQL.

```
@t1 = 
SELECT
    Regex.Match("ID=881cf2f5f474579a:T=1489536183:S=ALNI_MZsMMpA4voGE4kQMYxooceW2AOr0Q", "ID=(?<ID>\\w+):T=(?<T>\\w+):S=(?<S>[\\w\\d_]*)") AS p
FROM
    (VALUES(1)) AS fe(n);

@t2 = 
SELECT
    p.Groups["ID"].Value AS gads_id,
    p.Groups["T"].Value AS gads_t,
    p.Groups["S"].Value AS gads_s
FROM
    @t1;

OUTPUT @t
TO "/inhabit/test.csv"
USING Outputters.Csv();
```

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     E_CSC_USER_INVALIDCOLUMNTYPE:
>   'System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match' cannot be used as column type.

**I know how to do it in a SQL way with EXPLODE/CROSS APPLY/GROUP BY. But may be it is possible to do without these dances?**

One more update

```
@t1 = 
SELECT
    Regex.Match("ID=881cf2f5f474579a:T=1489536183:S=ALNI_MZsMMpA4voGE4kQMYxooceW2AOr0Q", "ID=(?<ID>\\w+):T=(?<T>\\w+):S=(?<S>[\\w\\d_]*)").Groups["ID"].Value AS id,
    Regex.Match("ID=881cf2f5f474579a:T=1489536183:S=ALNI_MZsMMpA4voGE4kQMYxooceW2AOr0Q", "ID=(?<ID>\\w+):T=(?<T>\\w+):S=(?<S>[\\w\\d_]*)").Groups["T"].Value AS t,
    Regex.Match("ID=881cf2f5f474579a:T=1489536183:S=ALNI_MZsMMpA4voGE4kQMYxooceW2AOr0Q", "ID=(?<ID>\\w+):T=(?<T>\\w+):S=(?<S>[\\w\\d_]*)").Groups["S"].Value AS s
FROM
    (VALUES(1)) AS fe(n);

OUTPUT @t1
TO "/inhabit/test.csv"
USING Outputters.Csv();
```

**This wariant works fine. But there is a question. Will the regex evauated 3 times per row? Does exists any chance to hint U-SQL engine - the function Regex.Match is deterministic.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably be using something more efficient than Regex.Match. But to answer your original question:

`System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match` is not part of the [built-in U-SQL types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt764123.aspx).

Thus you would need to convert it into a built-in type, such as `string` or `SqlArray<string>` or wrap it into a [udt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-analytics/data-lake-analytics-u-sql-programmability-guide) that provides an `IFormatter` to make it a user-defined type.

Comment: thank you as always, gonna use simple string's operations like Split or may be Substring only. because looks like the strings consists from parts with a constant lengths. one simple question. wich string's operations are codegened to a native code? are all string's operations like substring/split/... lead to .net calls or maybe there is exists a set of string's operations that compiled to a native code?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is better to use something like this to parse the simple strings. Regexes are slow for the task and if i will use simple string expressions (instead of CLR calls) they probably will be translated into c++ code at codegen phase... and .net interop will be eliminated (i'm not sure).

```
@t1 = 
SELECT
    pv.cust_gads != null ? new SQL.ARRAY<string>(pv.cust_gads.Split(':')) : null AS p
FROM
    dwh.raw_page_view_data AS pv
WHERE
    pv.year == "2017" AND
    pv.month == "04";

@t3 = 
SELECT
    p != null && p.Count == 3 ? p[0].Split('=')[1] : null AS id,
    p != null && p.Count == 3 ? p[1].Split('=')[1] : null AS t,
    p != null && p.Count == 3 ? p[2].Split('=')[1] : null AS s
FROM
    @t1 AS t1;

OUTPUT @t3
TO "/tmp/test.csv"
USING Outputters.Csv();
```