# Regular expression match U-SQL

Tags: regex, u-sql

I need a help in writing in U-SQL to output records to two different files based on a regular expression output.
Let me explain my scenario in detail.

Let us assume my input file has two columns, "Name" and person identification number ("PIN"):

```
Name , PIN
John ,12345
Harry ,01234
Tom, 24659
```

My condition for PIN is it should start with either 1 or 2. In the above case records 1 & 3 are valid and record 2 is invalid.

I need to output record 1 & 3 to my output processed file and 2 to my error file

How can I do this and also can I use `Regex.Match` to validate the regular expression?

```
//posting my code

@person =
EXTRACT UserId          int,
         PNR     string,
         UID String,
FROM "/Samples/Data/person.csv"
USING Extractors.csv();

@rs1=select UserId,PNR,UID,Regex.match(PNR,'^(19|20)[0-9]{2}((0[1-9])$') as pnrval,Regex.match(UID,'^(19|20)[0-9]{2}$') as uidval
from @person

@rs2 = select UserId,PNR,UID from @rs1 where pnrval=true or uidval=true
@rs3 = select UserId,PNR,UID from @rs1 where uidval=false or uidval= false

OUTPUT @rs2   
    TO "/output/sl.csv"
      USING Outputters.Csv();

OUTPUT @rs3   
    TO "/output/error.csv"
      USING Outputters.Csv();
```

But I'm receiving this error:

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error
>   E_CSC_USER_INVALIDCOLUMNTYPE: 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match'
>   cannot be used as column type.

Comment: Can you use C# to process your files?

Comment: Yes I can use C#. I thought of writing a function to validate this record and create some thing like a 3 column result set where the 3rd column will store the validation result  and filter records based on that column and write to output files But this logic seems to a little complex when i have to validate multiple columns.

Comment: Ok, then I'll write C# code in a couple of hours  to use regex.match

Comment: Can you post code if you already have it?

Comment: I will wait for your code. I have predefined regex patterns defined for each field  in each file. What i mentioned in my question is a sample . The problem for me is writing to error and processed file when a rule for a field fails

Comment: It's not a problem, just the rules for a question here actually ask to show some code (even if it doesn't work) to better focus on what's important rather then writing things the asker already knows / has done. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have added the code to my question

Comment: Great, I updated my answer. Let me know if it's clear and works for you.

Comment: Thank you. In USQl i will be writing the output to Azure data laje .In C# do i need to write code to connect  to ADL

Comment: I don't think so, at least... not necessarily. If you process in C# your CSV (either locally or via web service), then later you can import it in U-SQL just like you were doing before. Let me know if everything is clear and if my answer satisfies you.

Answer (score 1):

```
@person =
EXTRACT UserId          int,
         PNR     string,
         UID String,
FROM "/Samples/Data/person.csv"
USING Extractors.csv();

@rs1=select UserId,PNR,UID,Regex.Ismatch(PNR,'^(19|20)[0-9]{2}((0[1-9])$') as pnrval,Regex.Ismatch(UID,'^(19|20)[0-9]{2}$') as uidval
from @person

@rs2 = select UserId,PNR,UID from @rs1 where pnrval=true or uidval=true


@rs3 = select UserId,PNR,UID from @rs1 where pnrval=false or uidval= false

OUTPUT @rs2   
    TO "/output/sl.csv"
      USING Outputters.Csv();

OUTPUT @rs3   
    TO "/output/error.csv"
      USING Outputters.Csv();
```

This worked for my requirement. Thanks for the support and suggestions

Answer (score 1):

```
@someData =
SELECT * FROM
    ( VALUES
    ("John", "12345"),
    ("Harry", "01234"),
    ("Tom", "24659")
    ) AS T(Name, pin);

@result1 =
    SELECT Name,
        pin
    FROM @someData
    WHERE pin.StartsWith("1") OR pin.StartsWith("2");

@result2 =
    SELECT Name,
        pin
    FROM @someData
    WHERE !pin.StartsWith("1") AND !pin.StartsWith("2");
```

Comment: Thank you but this solution will not work in my case where i need to check for more than one condition in my regular expression

Comment: "My condition for PIN is it should start with either 1 or 2."

Answer (score 0):

Considering your input, I would use

```
.*\s*,\s*[12]\d+
```

- `.*` matches any amount of characters and is needed to match everything before the comma
- `\s*,\s*` matches a comma optionally preceded and or followed by any amount of blanks (`\s` matches a blank)
- `[12]` matches a single digit, equal to 1 or 2; this satisfies your requirement about PINs
- `\d+` matches one or more digits

Live demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/6uDKeA/3).

As far as using `Regex.Match`, I'll quote [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43288493/5480409) on StackOverflow:

> `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match` is not part of the built-in U-SQL types.

So what I would do here is pre-parsing your CSV in C#; something like:

```
        Regex CurrentRegex = new Regex(@".*\s*,\s*[12]\d+", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        foreach (var LineOfText in File.ReadAllLines(InputFilePath))
        {
            Match CurrentMatch = CurrentRegex.Match(LineOfText);
            if (CurrentMatch.Success)
            {
                // Append line to success file
            }
            else
            {
                // Append line to error file
            }
            CurrentMatch = CurrentMatch.NextMatch();
        }
```

Comment: `[\s]` is better written just `\s`. Answering questions where the OP demonstrates no attempt of their own is slightly dubious.

Comment: Dubious meaning...? however yes, you are right about those brackets

Comment: See e.g. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69798/is-stack-overflow-a-code-writing-service

Comment: @tripleee, thanks, I updated my answer and the OP posted his/her code. I'm actively using StackOverflow since last October, can I ask why you are looking for "feedback on the tail end of my answers on Stack Overflow"? Is there a reason to delete someone's own answers? Thank you, best regards

Comment: I have deleted some old answers which had a downvote where ultimately I agreed with the downvoter's (apparent) feedback that they did not provide a lot of value. Optimistically, I can always hope to receive a balancing upvote on the remaining ones. Removing less stellar content of your own is a good way to help keep the site's quality up and your own record neat.